# DataGridView select Row Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I build a auto-suggestive search with a textbox and a DGV. Everything works fine, besides that I do wanna have 2 buttons which offer functionality to go 1 row up or down. You have to know, that while I am searching I set those rows that don't contain the search-string to `.visible = false`.

In theory it should work like this:

```
Private Sub tsbDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbDown.Click
    With dgvMA
       If dgvMA.RowCount > 0 Then
            Dim MyDesiredIndex As Integer = GetNextVisibleCell(dgvMA.CurrentRow.Index)

            dgvMA.ClearSelection()
            dgvMA.CurrentCell = dgvMA.Rows(MyDesiredIndex).Cells(1)
            dgvMA.Rows(MyDesiredIndex).Selected = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetNextVisibleCell(currentrow As Integer) As Integer
    With dgvMA
        For i = currentrow To .Rows.Count - 1
            If .Rows(i).Visible = True Then
                MsgBox(i & ": " & .Rows(i).Visible)
                Return i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Return currentrow
    End With
End Function
```

but NEVER EVER my row gets selected. `multi-select` is set to `false`, and `fullrowselect` to `true`. when I click on a row manually or it gets selected with the keyboard everything is printed properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Private Sub tsbDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbDown.Click
    With dgvMA
        If dgvMA.RowCount > 0 And dgvMA.CurrentRow.Index + 1 < dgvMA.Rows.Count Then
            Dim MyDesiredIndex As Integer = GetNextVisibleCell(dgvMA.CurrentRow.Index + 1)

            dgvMA.ClearSelection()
            dgvMA.CurrentCell = dgvMA.Rows(MyDesiredIndex).Cells(1)
            dgvMA.Rows(MyDesiredIndex).Selected = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub tsbUp_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsbUp.Click
    With dgvMA
        If dgvMA.RowCount > 0 And dgvMA.CurrentRow.Index <> 0 Then
            Dim MyDesiredIndex As Integer = GetNextVisibleCell(dgvMA.CurrentRow.Index - 1)

            dgvMA.ClearSelection()
            dgvMA.CurrentCell = dgvMA.Rows(MyDesiredIndex).Cells(1)
            dgvMA.Rows(MyDesiredIndex).Selected = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetNextVisibleCell(currentrow As Integer) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    With dgvMA
        For i = currentrow To .Rows.Count - 1
            If .Rows(i).Visible = True Then
                ' MsgBox(i & ": " & .Rows(i).Visible)
                Return i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Return currentrow
    End With
End Function
```

P.S. I didn't check the code that gets next visible cell but it seems ok and row selection works fine